# Can we use torch.multiprocessing.spawn with wandb sweep hyper-parameter tuning?

Tags: pytorch, wandb, pytorch-distributions

Can we use `torch.multiprocessing.spawn` with `wandb.sweep` (https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/sweeps).

```py
torch.multiprocessing.spawn(func, nprocs=world_size, join=True)
```

I tried but got errors and cannot find tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Python's standard `multiprocessing` library to spawn agents for a `wandb.sweep`:

```py
import multiprocessing
import wandb
    
def init():
    '''set up config and start sweep'''
    sweep_config = {
        'method': 'grid',
        'name': 'sweep',
        'metric': {
            'goal': 'minimize',
            'name': 'val_loss'
        },
        'parameters': {
            'net': {'values': ['unet', 'swinunetr']},
            'batch_size': {'values': [1, 16, 32, 64, 128]},
            'lr': {'values': [1e-1, 1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5]},
            'patch_size': {'values': [32, 64, 128, 256]},
            'samples_per_slice': {'values': [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]}
        }
    }
    
    # count num of combinations for grid sweep
    sweep_count = 1
    for key in sweep_config['parameters']:
        sweep_count *= len(sweep_config['parameters'][key]['values'])
    
    sweep_id = wandb.sweep(sweep=sweep_config, project='proj', )
    
    return sweep_id, sweep_count
    
def main():
    '''training code goes here'''
    # connect agent to sweep and import configs/params
    wandb.init()
    config = {
        'net': wandb.config.net,
        'batch_size': wandb.config.batch_size,
        'lr': wandb.config.lr,
        'patch_size': wandb.config.patch_size,
        'samples_per_slice': wandb.config.samples_per_slice,
    }
    print(config)
    wandb.log(config)
    ### ADD YOUR TRAINING CODE HERE
    
def agent(sweep_id, sweep_count):
    '''run agent'''
    wandb.agent(sweep_id, function=main, count=sweep_count, project='proj')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # initialize sweep
    sweep_id, sweep_count = init()
    # spawn and run 4 agents for the sweep
    procs = []
    for _ in range(4):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=agent, args=[sweep_id, sweep_count])
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)
    for p in procs:
        p.join()
```

This dumps all `wandb` logs into a single terminal window, which I haven't yet figured out.